# How to use Google Chrome with Developer Tools with Selenium RC

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-rc, google-chrome-devtools

I can open a google chrome browser like this:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium(Server, ServerPort,
                                          "*googlechrome", DomainURL);
```

but it would be really useful to have it opened with the Chrome Developer Tools enabled, to be able to debug problems when developing the tests.

I can't manage to enable them, anybody knows about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom profile that have developer tools enabled. Selenium is starting Chrome with a new clean profile each and every time you use it. Selenium 1 does not offer a mechanism for overriding this. Selenium 2's ChromeDriver, however, can use an example profile.

You can try using Firefox with Firebug